# How can I modify the default behaviour of Ubuntu 12.04 (& 12.10) to prevent a symbolic link from /dev/shm to /run/shm ever being created on boot up?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, mount, oracle, shm

Whilst installing Oracle 11gR2 Express Edition on Ubuntu 12.04 by following the [Oracle 11gR2 Express Edition on Linux Ubuntu 11.10 howto](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639&start=0&tstart=0) and have encountered the Oracle memory target problem with `/dev/shm` (as documented in section 7. of that guide)  since `/dev/shm` is now implemented by default as a symbolic link as noted in the Ubuntu 11.10 release notes from `/dev/shm` to `/run/shm`.  The symbolic link is incompatible with what Oracle expects and this results in an Oracle error (ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET) on database startup.

Section 7) of the 'Oracle 11gR2 Express Edition on Linux Ubuntu 11.10 howto' documents a startup script `/etc/init.d/oracle-shm` that is meant to configure `/dev/shm` to use Ubuntu’s `/run/shm`, however this does *not* appear to have the desired effect on Ubuntu 12.04 and `/dev/shm` is not mounted as expected - presumably it did work on 11.10.   Although this has [already been noted and various solutions proposed](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2376116) I chose to work around the problem in a slightly different way by adding an entry to `/etc/fstab` and modifying the `/etc/init.d/oracle-shm` script as follows:

1. Adding an entry for the shared memory temporary file system to `/etc/fstab`, say (for a 2 gigabyte file)

   ```
   shm /dev/shm    tmpfs   size=2g 0   0
   ```
2. Changing the `mount` line in `/etc/init.d/oracle-shm` from:

   ```
   rm -f /dev/shm  
   mkdir /dev/shm
   mount -B /run/shm /dev/shm
   ```

   to simply

   ```
   rm -f /dev/shm
   mkdir /dev/shm 
   mount /dev/shm
   ```

Regardless, all the proposed solutions involve undoing the default Ubuntu behaviour at bootup, by first removing the symbolic link and then implementing the desired behaviour.

I would like to be able to setup the shared memory file system *once and for all* by:

1. Adding an entry for the shared memory temporary file system to `/etc/fstab`, say (for a 2 gigabyte file)

   ```
   shm /dev/shm    tmpfs   size=2g 0   0
   ```
2. Remove the existing symbolic link to /dev/shm and create as a directory, as sudo.

   ```
   rm –f /dev/shm
   mkdir /dev/shm
   ```
3. Mounting the shared memory temporary file system

   ```
   mount /dev/shm
   ```

This all works fine until you reboot, at which point the symbolic link from `/dev/shm` to `/run/shm` re-appears instead of `/dev/shm` being mounted as a shared memory temporary file system.

Here’s the question then.

*How can I modify the default behaviour of Ubuntu 12.04 (& 12.10) to prevent a symbolic link from `/dev/shm` to `/run/shm` ever being created in the first place on boot up?*

action=show&redirect=OneiricOcelot/TechnicalOverview#Upgrades

Comment: Note also https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/ora-00845-memory_target-error-installing-oracle-xe-on-mint-and-ubuntu/ which rather moves and rebinds `/dev/shm`  to `/run/shm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `/etc/init/mounted-dev.conf` remove the line

```
 [ -e /dev/shm ] || ln -s /run/shm /dev/shm
```

Comment: Thank you Florian for a fantastic response. The symbolic link is now not created and my temporary file system is mounted on /dev/shm as expected - works like a dream.  Now the /etc/init.d/oracle-shm script is not required at all.

Comment: The comment above that line says "With the /run transition, shm lives there now, but eglibc still looks in /dev/shm. So create a symlink there". How concerned should I be about side effects of removing this?